# TaskBar like behavior in a region in vb6

Tags: windows, winapi, vb6

I'm looking for code that will make a particular region act like a taskbar space. The code must be in VB6. Like the taskbar, that region should be empty even when a window is maximized. It is for a form which will act like a taskbar.

Comment: In other words, how to restrict the dimensions of all other fullscreen windows.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished via the [`SHAppBarMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762108%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API. [Here](http://www.thescarms.com/VBasic/appbar.aspx) is a working demo in VB6.